# Android Calendar Manipulation

Tags: android, string, calendar

I am working on the Calendar manipulation. The code is as follows:

### Code:

```
        int dd =0;
        int mm =0;
        int yy =0;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        try
        {
            dd = Integer.parseInt(next2_draw_date.substring(0,2));
            mm = Integer.parseInt(next2_draw_date.substring(3,5));
            yy = Integer.parseInt(next2_draw_date.substring(6,10));
            c.set(yy, mm, dd, 21, 15);

            Calendar N = Calendar.getInstance();
            N.set(yy, mm, dd, 21, 15);
            Date NX = N.getTime();  
            Format df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.UK);
            String X = df.format(NX);

            tv_open.setText("Date1" + next2_draw_date + "\n" + dd +"/ /"+ mm + "/ /" + yy + "/ /"+ X); 

            c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -before); // subtract x hour
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            c.set(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0);            
        }
```

### Question:

The next2_draw_date below is 05/11/2016 9:15PM, and dd, mm, yy can be extracted successfully as 5, 11, 2016 respectively.

The Date1 however shown is 05/12/2016 21:15. Why it does not show 05/11/2016?

Comment: set your calendar using this format calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your calendar using this format

```
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

Comment: why especially month need to deduct by 1? why no need for day of month or year?

Comment: thanks and noted that Months are indexed from 0 not 1, so 10 is November and 11 will be December, the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH